# What does !() mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6

I just saw this construction for the first time in javascript

```js
if (someConditionIsMet && !(anotherCondition && oneMoreCondition)) {
  return something
}
```

There is a !() inside of the if-conditional statement. I'm wondering what exactly that does. Is it just a way of grouping several conditions together and making sure they all evaluate a certain way before triggering logic? If so, is this merely to simplify the appearance or is there some logical advantage here?

Comment: Not the entire expression. && is executed first then the not. I'm glad you're learning something.

Comment: `!` is the logical NOT operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically for `!(anotherCondition && oneMoreCondition)`, it means `NOT (anotherCondition AND oneMoreCondition)`.

This is [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
not (A and B) = not A or not B
```

Some might say that `not A or not B` is easier to read than `not (A and B)` but that's personal preference.

Expanding the whole condition using De Morgan's law would result in:

```
someConditionIsMet AND (NOT anotherCondition OR NOT oneMoreCondition)
```

in Javascript:

```
if (someConditionIsMet && (!anotherCondition || !oneMoreCondition))
```

You can use that expanded form if you think it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

!() In any case in javascript means that if they are NOT true. So basically like in this case...

```
if(!(anotherCondition && oneMoreCondition)) {
Console.log("If both set to false this would run!");
}
```

if anotherCondition and oneMoreCondition were both set to false this would actually return true. This here might help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_!

Answer (score 0):

It's evaluating the condition of anotherCondition && oneMoreCondition, and then reversing it.

So if the condition evaluates to true, the ! makes the condition evaluate to false.